# Coloring medial part of deltoid muscle

Tags: anatomy

I want to draw the deltoid muscle and color the medial deltoid. I could not find a 3D anatomical structure for the medial deltoid, so I'm unsure how to proceed.

```
AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Deltoid"]]
```

This draws the deltoid muscles.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the "AcromialPartOfDeltoid" entity.

```
AnatomyPlot3D[
 {
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Deltoid"],
  Blue, Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "AcromialPartOfDeltoid"]
  }
 ]
```

[image: plotted delts]

I found this entity name (and all other parts of the deltoids) by doing

```
Select[AnatomyData["EntityCanonicalNames"], StringContainsQ["Deltoid"]]
```

and scanning through the results (and reading the wikipedia page about deltoids for other names of medial deltoids )